# Spring boot REST API best way to choose in client side which field to load

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, load, rest

Hi I have implemented a mock solution to my problem and I'm pretty sure something better already exist.
Here's that I want to achieve :
I have created a point to load categories with or without subCategories
/api/categories/1?fields=subCategories
returns

```
{ 
  "id":"1",
  "name":"test",
  "subCategories":[{
     "id":"1",
      "name":"test123"


    }]
}
```

/api/categories/1
returns

```
{ 
  "id":"1",
  "name":"test"
 }
```

My entities

```
  @Entity
    class Category{
      @Id
      private String id;
      private String name;
      private Set<SubCategory> subCategories;

    
    }
@Entity
class SubCategory{
     @Id
     private String id;
     private String name;
}
```

I have removed services since this is not the point.

I've created CategoryDTO and SubCategoryDTO classes with the same fields as Category and SubCategory

The converter

```
class CategoryDTOConverter{
     CategoryDTO convert(Category category,String fields){
             CategoryDTO dto=new CategoryDTO();
             dto.setName(category.getName());
             if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(fields) && fields.contains("subCategories"){
                  category.getSubCategories().forEach(s->{
                         dto.getSubcategories().add(SubCategoryDTOConverter.convert(s));
                 }
              }
     }
}
```

I used com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository to create an EntityGraph from a list of attribute path

```
@Repository
interface CategoryRepository extends EntityGraphJpaRepository<Category, String>{
        Optional<T> findById(String id,EntityGraph entityGraph);


}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryController {
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<CategoryDTO> get(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam(value="fields",required=false) String fields ) throws Exception {
        
       Optional<Category> categOpt=repository.findById(id,fields!=null?EntityGraphUtils.fromAttributePaths(fields):null);
        if(categOpt.isEmpty()) 
            throws new NotFoundException();

       return ResponseEntity.ok(categoryDTOConverter.convert(categOpt.get(),fields);
    }
}
```

This is a simple example to illustrate what I need to do
I don't want to load fields that clients doesn't want to use

How could I do this in a better way ?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your problem ? I also want to implement resource expansion/field selection on a REST API. 

Main problem at the moment is that Hibernate throws `LazyInitializationException` on the fields that the client did not want but the mapper is trying to fetch (MapStruct implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) since it is a perfect match for your use case. With GraphQL it is the client that decides which attributes it wants to receive by providing in the POST request body exactly which attributes are needed to be included in the response. This is way more manageable than trying to handle all this on your own.

Spring Boot recently added its own [Spring GraphQL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/) library, so it is quite simple to integrate it in your Spring Boot app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already knew graphql but I'm working on an existing rest api and I don't think I have the time to redefine all api points and for consistency I don't want to mix GraphQL and Rest. It must be an easy way of doing it with Rest api.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is easy or even clean, but you might take a look at `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` which is a Jackson filter. For that, you would need to return `MappingJacksonValue` instead of whatever you are returning in your Controller methods defining the endpoints. You can find an example at https://www.javatpoint.com/restful-web-services-dynamic-filtering.

Comment: Another possibility would be to implement a `ResponseBodyAdvice` that would filter the unwanted attributes before writing the response. You can find more information about it at http://www.javabyexamples.com/quick-guide-to-responsebodyadvice-in-spring-mvc. Still, I wouldn't say any of the solutions is easy or even clean.

Comment: Thanks for you answeres SimpleBeanPropertyFilter seems to be simpler than ResponseBodyAdvice. 
I think ResponseBodyAdvice is the best solution of thoses but It doesn't answere to my lazy initialisation issues, if I don't need subCategories I don't want that hibernate load  category.getSubCategories() when I will convert my Category to CategoryDTO.

Comment: @ScorprocS Exactly this  ! I'm facing the same issue where I only want to fetch lazy-loaded entities if client needs them and it seems the viable way to do it is the one you've described in your question